# I have previously created buttons etc from within photoshop and then saved them out for web. Should I now be using css to create my buttons for me?

Tags: css

I have previously created buttons and other graphics (footer bars) from within photoshop and then saved them out for web.  Should I now be using css to create my buttons for me? I noticed these are quite code heavy.

Comment: Yes. Buttons should not be the gaudiest thing on your web page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to but the reason using css is considered the better way is because you will not need to make an extra http request to get the image. It really is personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If the design, you previously made, satisfies your goals there is no necessity to change it. But if you want to use advantages of CSS and if you are not scared of some problems with browsers which do not support CSS completely or support it with some bugs, you can create new CSS elements.

Here are *some* advantages and disadvantages of both ways.

Images

```
   + cross-browser solution. Easier to make GUI look the same way in all browsers.
   - extra requests to the server
   - extra traffic downloaded by users
   - the page will weight more and load longer time
   - much more time needed to make some little changes in the GUI appearance
```

CSS

```
   + no extra requests to the server
   + no extra traffic downloaded by users
   + the page will weight less and load faster
   + less time needed to make changes in the GUI appearance
   - NOT a cross-browser solution. Harder to make GUI look the same way in all browsers.
```

As you can see, CSS has more advantages, but it is way harder to make a cross-browser design using it.

P.S. I'm sorry for my poor language.

Answer (score 0):

Generally using code for things like buttons is currently the way to go. Buttons created in photoshop tend to look gimmicky (currently) and, if you look at the majority of websites you'll notice buttons are very clean, usually subtle gradients and slight box-shadows or such. With the benefit of not having an extra http request this gives it even more of an edge to use code to create such things.

There are many tools and pre-made buttons available to help create the buttons.

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) buttons are very clean and widely used. (You don't have to use the whole bootstrap system to use them, just look at their code and re-create :))

Or to customise your own button you can use websites such as [CSS button generator](http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/)